# SQL primary key statement

Tags: android, sql, jooq

I am trying to create a new table in SQL in an Android App. I am using jOOQ for that. This table has one primary key with two columns. This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE form_field (
 form_id INTEGER REFERENCES form(_id) NOT NULL
,form_key TEXT NOT NULL
,form_value TEXT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (form_id, form_key)
);
```

but in the jOOQ auto generated classes my table 'form_filed' doesn't have the properties 'form_id', 'form_key' and 'form_value'. if I write this instead of the code above everything works...

```
CREATE TABLE form_field (
 form_id INTEGER REFERENCES form(_id) NOT NULL
,form_key TEXT NOT NULL
,form_value TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Does someone know where is the problem??Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The table has ONE primary key, a composite one with two columns!

Comment: Yes sorry you are right I edit my question

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The generated table contains all the relevant columns. What jOOQ version are you using?

Comment: I am using the version 3.5.3

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried using later versions? Could you provide more information to help reproduce this? E.g. your code generator configuration, the `form` table definition, etc.